# Provide <Realm/> info to Tomcat on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Our web application has an `appName.xml` file in our Tomcat directory structure at `<tomcatInstall>/conf/Catalina/localhost/`. Its entire text is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context crossContext="true">
  <Realm className="com.blah.ApDataSourceRealm" 
         dataSourceName="jdbc/blahDev" 
         roleNameCol="blahRole" 
         userCredCol="blahToken" 
         userNameCol="blahCol" 
         userRoleTable="blahTable" 
         userTable="blahTable"
  />
</Context>
```

I made sure to delete the tomcat 8 install in eclipse and then add it back again; I understand that is what copies all the tomcat installation stuff to the workspace locations. When I attempt to run the server on eclipse, the login page is displayed, but the username/password is always rejected.

I fixed it once by finding the eclipse copy of server.xml in the eclipse-workspace folder tree (`...eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/temp1/conf`). But the next time I rebooted the computer and ran it again, the login failed, and on checking server.xml, I find that it was overwritten this morning. I assume eclipse overwrites it under some conditions, perhaps on eclipse startup? I put the `<Realm ... />` tag into server.xml within `<Context ... />` again, and it is working again.

Where should this information go? I'd like to put it somewhere that it won't disappear from eclipse. I don't think we want this realm tag in the actual server.xml (as opposed to the one local to eclipse), because this one is specific to the development environment. So where can it be put on my machine so that it is used by eclipse's Tomcat and yet doesn't interfere with the application's overall source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way is to put your `<Context>` configuration in the  `webapp/META-INF/context.xml`.

[Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) :

> Individual Context elements may be explicitly defined:
>
> - In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application
>     files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML attribute) this may be
>     copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to
>     application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.
> - In individual
>     files (with a ".xml" extension) in the
>     $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory. The context
>     path and version will be derived from the base name of the file (the
>     file name less the .xml extension). This file will always take
>     precedence over any context.xml file packaged in the web application's
>     META-INF directory.
> - Inside a Host element in the main conf/server.xml.
>
> Default Context elements may be defined that apply to multiple web
>   applications. Configuration for an individual web application will
>   override anything configured in one of these defaults

---

> Where should this information go? I'd like to put it somewhere that it
>   won't disappear from eclipse
>
> So where can it be put on my machine so
>   that it is used by eclipse's Tomcat and yet doesn't interfere with the
>   application's overall source?

When you create a Tomcat in Eclipse , a server project will also be created. This project stores the configuration for the created tomcat instance which will be copied to Tomcat instance 's `conf` folder (i.e. `eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/temp1/conf` when tomcat starts.

[image]

So , if you do not want to add the Realm configuration to your project source codes likes `/webapp/META-INF/context.xml` , you can add it to the `context.xml` in the server project.

Comment: This seems to be instructions on how to define a context element in different ways in Tomcat. I will try the ones that I can figure out. But I was hoping someone could address the question of how to make this work *in eclipse*, either using how it's currently defined running on Tomcat itself, or some other compatible way (e.g., not putting environment-specific things in an otherwise environment-agnostic file).

Comment: @arcy , Ok . Understand your question now and see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks -- I've upvoted and accepted your solution. I do have a suggestion: when you update an answer, do it in a way that maintains the original answer (add to bottom, for instance). If you modify the original text the way you have, then comments that referred to the original text don't make much sense, and the entire question becomes a less good resource for people coming afterwards. If that isn't possible, then I suggest creating an entire new answer.